# Slow data.frame row assignation

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I am working with RMongoDB and I need to fill an empty data.frame with the values of a query. The results are quite long, about 2 milion documents (rows).

While I was doing performance tests, I found out that the time for writing the values to a row increases by the dimension of the data frame. Maybe it is a well known issue and I am the last one to notice it.

Some code example:

```
set.seed(20140430)
nreg <- 2e3
dfres <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,nreg*7),nrow=nreg,ncol=7))
system.time(dfres[1e3,] <-  c(1:5,"a","b"))
summary(replicate(10,system.time(dfres[sample(1:nreg,1),] <- c(1:5,"a","b"))[3]))

nreg <- 2e6
dfres <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,nreg*7),nrow=nreg,ncol=7))
system.time(dfres[1e3,] <-  c(1:5,"a","b"))
summary(replicate(10,system.time(dfres[sample(1:nreg,1),] <- c(1:5,"a","b"))[3]))
```

On my machine, the assignment at the 2 milion rows data.frame takes about 0.4 seconds. This is a lot of time if I want to fill the whole dataset. Here goes a second simulation in order to draw the issue.

```
nreg <- seq(2e1,2e7,length.out=10)
te <- NULL 
for(i in nreg){
    dfres <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,i*7),nrow=i,ncol=7))
    te <- c(te,mean(replicate(10,{r <- sample(1:i,1); system.time(dfres[r,] <- c(1:5,"a","b"))[3]}) ) )
}
plot(nreg,te,xlab="Number of rows",ylab="Avg. time for 10 random assignments [sec]",type="o")
#rm(nreg,dfres,te)
```

[image]

**Question**: Why this happens? Is there a quicker way to fill the data.frame in memory?

Comment: A workarround: it consists in assigning rows in a temporal data.frame with 1e4 rows until it is full. Then I rbind it with the final data.frame and refill the small one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's start with "columns" first and see what goes on and then return to rows.

R versions < 3.1.0 (unnecessarily) copies the entire `data.frame` when you operate on them. For example:

```
## R v3.0.3
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
dplyr:::changes(df, transform(df, z=11:15)) ## requires dplyr to be available

# Changed variables:
#           old            new           
# x         0x7ff9343fb4d0 0x7ff9326dfba8
# y         0x7ff9343fb488 0x7ff9326dfbf0
# z         <added>        0x7ff9326dfc38

# Changed attributes:
#           old            new           
# names     0x7ff934170c28 0x7ff934308808
# row.names 0x7ff934551b18 0x7ff934308970
# class     0x7ff9346c5278 0x7ff935d1d1f8
```

You can see that addition of "new" column has resulted in a copy of the "old" columns (the addresses are different). Also the attributes are copied. What bites most is that these copies are *deep copies*, as opposed to *shallow copies*.

> Shallow copies only copy the vector of column pointers, not the entire data, where as deep copies copy everything (which is unnecessary here).

However, in R v3.1.0, there has been nice welcoming changes in that the "old" columns are not *deep* copied. All credits to the R core dev team.

```
## R v3.1.0
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
dplyr:::changes(df, transform(df, z=11:15)) ## requires dplyr to be available

# Changed variables:
#           old     new           
# z         <added> 0x7f85d328dda8

# Changed attributes:
#           old            new           
# names     0x7f85d1459548 0x7f85d297bec8
# row.names 0x7f85d2c66cd8 0x7f85d2bfa928
# class     0x7f85d345cab8 0x7f85d2d6afb8
```

You can see that the columns `x` and `y` aren't changed at all (and therefore not present in the output of `changes` function call). This is a huge (and welcoming) improvement!

So far, we looked at the issue in adding columns in R <3.1.0 and v3.1.0

---

Now, coming to your question: so, what about the "rows"? Let's consider older version of R first and then come back to R v3.1.0.

```
## R v3.0.3
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
df.old <- df
df$y[1L] <- -6L
dplyr:::changes(df.old, df)

# Changed variables:
#           old            new           
# x         0x7f968b423e50 0x7f968ac6ba40
# y         0x7f968b423e98 0x7f968ac6bad0
# 
# Changed attributes:
#           old            new           
# names     0x7f968ab88a28 0x7f968abca8e0
# row.names 0x7f968abb6438 0x7f968ab22bb0
# class     0x7f968ad73e08 0x7f968b580828
```

Once again we see that changing column `y` has resulted in copying column `x` as well in older versions of R.

```
## R v3.1.0
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
df.old <- df
df$y[1L] <- -6L
dplyr:::changes(df.old, df)

# Changed variables:
#           old            new           
# y         0x7f85d3544090 0x7f85d2c9bbb8
# 
# Changed attributes:
#           old            new           
# row.names 0x7f85d35a69a8 0x7f85d35a6690
```

We see the nice improvements in R v3.1.0 which has resulted in the copy of *just* column `y`. Once again, great improvements in R v3.1.0! R's copy-on-modify has gotten wiser.

> But still, using `data.table`'s *assignment by reference* semantics, we can do one step better - not copy even the `y` column as is the case in R v3.1.0.
>
> The idea being: as long as the type of the object you assign to a column at certain indices don't change (here, column `y` is integer - so as long as you assign an integer back to `y`), we *really* can do it without having to copy by modifying *in-place* (by reference).
>
> Why? Because we don't have to allocate/re-allocate anything here. As an example, if you had assigned a double/numeric type, which requires 8 bytes of storage as opposed to 4-bytes of storage for integer column `y`, then we've to create a new column `y` and copy values back.

That is, we can *sub-assign by reference* using `data.table`. We can use either `:=` or `set()` to do this. I'll demonstrate using `set()` here.

Now, here's a comparison with base R and `data.table` on your data with 2,000 to 20,000,000 rows in multiples of 10, against R v3.0.3 and v3.1.0 separately. [You can find the code here](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/91b9951a57ce85090104).

Plot for comparison against R v3.0.3:

[image: R3.0.3 vs data.table]

Plot for comparison against R v3.1.0:
[image: 3.1.0 vs data.table]

The min, median and max for R v3.0.3, R v3.1.0 and data.table on 20 million rows with 10 replications are:

```
      type    min  median    max
base_3.0.3  10.05   10.70  18.51
base_3.1.0   1.67    1.97   5.20
data.table   0.04    0.04   0.05
```

> Note: You can see the complete timings in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/91b9951a57ce85090104).

This clearly shows the improvement in R v3.1.0, but also shows that the column which is being changed is still being copied and that still consumes sometime, which is overcome through *sub-assignment by reference* in `data.table`.

HTH

Comment: Great detailed answer.